# JSF making GET requests from a PrimeFaces paging grid

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Let's say I have the following:

```
public class User {

    private String userId;

    private String name;

    private String lastName;

    private String socialSecurity;

    private int age;

    private List<User> listUsers;

    private User selectedUser;

    // getters and setters

}
```

I also have a service class to get the data from the database

```
public class UserService {

        public List<User> getUsers() {

            /* select statement to return all users from DB */

            return users;

        }

    }
```

And a Controller class set as @ViewScoped

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public Class UserController {

// initialize User and UserService

    private User user;

    private UserService service;

    //getters and setters

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        user = new User();

        service = new UserService();

        //load all the users from the DB and store them on the listUsers
        user.setListUsers(service.getUsers());

    }

    public String selectUser()
    {
        return "index.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

Now imagine that I have a JSF form where the user can enter the name of the user, last name, age and all the properties. The user ID field is a read-only field. Below the userId field there is a link that says: "Search an existing user". If they click that link, it would take them to a search screen where they see all users in a selectable primeface datatable. Something like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="userSearch" var="user" rows="10"
                value="#{userController.user.listUsers}" paginator="true"
                selection="#{userController.user.selectedUser}"
                rowKey="#{user.userId}">
                <f:facet name="header"> Users </f:facet>

        <p:column selectionMode="single"
            style="width:16px;text-align:center" />

        <p:column headerText="User ID" sortBy="#{user.userId}">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.userId}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{user.name}">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Last Name" sortBy="#{user.lastName}">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}" />
        </p:column>

</p:dataTable>

    <p:commandButton value="Select User" icon="fa fa-save" action="#{userController.selectUser}">

    <f:setPropertyActionListener
        value="#{userController.user.selectedUser}"
        target="#{userController.user}" />

</p:commandButton>
```

When they select a user and click on 'Select', I want to redirect the user to the main screen and pre-populate the fields with the data from the selected user. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Notice that inside the button I am using `setPropertyActionListener` but this only works when I make the controller class an ApplicationScoped. If it is a ViewScoped, it doesn't work. I think this is a good solution but I can't make it ApplicationScoped because data should be different for all users. What can I do here to make this work?

I created this example to explain what my goal is but it is not my real scenario. What I have in mind in doing is creating a GET request when they click on Select and in the view itself, I check if a GET request exists. If there is a GET request, I populate the fields with the GET request data. Is this the best way to do that or is there another way? Perhaps making the controller class a RequestedScope bean?

The point is that I want the user to be able to search for existing data (in this case existing users), search for one of them, select it and go back to the previous screen to update the data.

I am using JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces 5.3 and OmniFaces 1.11

Comment: Sorry, but this question is _way_ too long, and it's not even clear what you are asking. "I created this example to explain what my goal is but it is not my real scenario." That's not the way to ask a question. Explain what you want to do, what you tried, and what did not work.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to communicate between two JSF pages. If that is your problem, consider reading http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html . There is also an example about GET.